# How to count the characters of jar files by wc

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, wc

Under the folder `/usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/` 
We have .jar files as the following

```
$ ls  /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/ | grep ".jar"
async-http-client-1.8.16.jar
azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.1.4.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-codec-1.4.jar
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar
commons-collections4-4.1.jar
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-lang-2.6.jar
commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
guava-11.0.2.jar
hadoop-aws-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
hadoop-azure-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
hadoop-azure-datalake-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
hadoop-yarn-server-timeline-pluginstorage-2.7.3.2.6.4.0-91.jar
jersey-client-1.9.jar
jersey-json-1.9.jar
jettison-1.3.4.jar
jetty-6.1.26.hwx.jar
jetty-util-6.1.26.hwx.jar
jsr305-3.0.0.jar
metrics-core-3.1.0.jar
protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
RoaringBitmap-0.4.9.jar
servlet-api-2.5.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
```

I want to count all characters from the .jar files by **wc** , in order to understand if .jar files renamed

So I do the following command in order to count all characters from all .jar files

```
ls  /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/ | grep ".jar" | sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc | awk '{print $NF}'
758
```

So in this case we get 758 characters from all `.jars`

But the command isn’t elegant

How we can improve the command to be better?

Comment: You want to get total string length of all the filename? That sounds like a strange request. Smells like an XY problem.

Comment: what I want it to count all characters from the output  by wc or any other suggestion

Comment: 1) Wouldn't it make sense to get the length of "each" filename? 2) That wouldn't really tell you a whole lot as it can be renamed to something with the same amount of letters. 3) There really isn't a way to tell if any of the files have been renamed unless a script runs something like `ls -l | awk '{print $NF} > jarlog.txt` so that you can compare the filenames.

Comment: look only I want is to improve the cli - ls  /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/ | grep ".jar" | sed s'/\// /g' | awk '{print $NF}' | wc | awk '{print $NF}'

Comment: this command is works fine but no so elegant , any way I want to count all charterers from the output that all

Comment: the reason for this check , is to know if file or files was renamed from some reason

Comment: Something like `printf '%s' *.jar | wc -c` you mean? Note that (unlike your original) this won't add/count newlines *between* filenames (and won't match things like `doorajar`)

Comment: `printf '%s\n' *.jar | md5sum` wouldn't be blind to renaming to something with the same amount of letters.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That would do it and there's an error on my part. Still, it would make sense to do it for each file rather than for the total number of characters. How would it even be known which file was renamed by the fact that there's a different number of characters???

Comment: You could calculate a hash like md5 over the sorted name list. Or even better calculate the md5 over the sorted md5sum file to detect any chance in names or content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you are looking for

```
basename -a /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/*.jar | wc -c
```

The path with wildcard list all jar files, the `basename` command strips directories (`-a` is needed to accept many arguments), and `wc -c` just counts bytes (if some filenames consist of 2 byte characters then perhaps `wc -m` (characters count) would be a better choice).

However, to if the goal is to check if files have been modified then perhaps `stat` (for modification time) or `md5sum`/`shasum` for checksum would be a better tools.

Comment: `wc -c` counts the number of bytes, not characters. `wc -m` counts the number of characters. Also note that you're also counting one extra newline character per file.

Comment: what is the diff between wc  -c to wc -m ?  ( because on both I get the same results )

Comment: @yael, `wc -m` counts the number of characters, `wc -c` the number of bytes. That makes a difference in the case of characters made of more than one byte (in UTF-8, that's all the non-ASCII ones (over a million of them)). Compare `printf € | wc -c` with `printf € | wc -m`.

Answer (score 5):

Counting the number of letters in the filenames would not be a safe way of detecting a renamed filename.

Instead, create a simple file listing of the names, and compare it to an existing list.  By using `diff`, you would be shown exactly which line(s) in the list had changed.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

LC_ALL=C

newlist=$HOME/filelist.new
oldlist=$HOME/filelist.old

echo /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/*.jar >"$newlist"

if [ -f "$oldlist" ]; then
    diff -u "$oldlist" "$newlist"
fi

mv "$newlist" "$oldlist"
```

Obviously, the first time you do this, `filelist.old` would not exist, so the `diff` would not run.

Note that I save the full path to each file in the output file. This does not matter since the directory path is static.

Change `echo` to `ls -l` if you want to also compare timestamps etc. Change it to `stat` if you want to compare even more meta data (this would generate diff output when even the last-access timestamp on a file changed).  Install `wdiff` and change `diff` to `wdiff` to get a word-based diff rather than a line-based one.

The `LC_ALL=C` is to guarantee a consistent sorting of the expansion of the shell glob.

Answer (score 3):

To just get the number of characters in the (non-hidden) `jar` filenames, I would do

```
cd /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/ && printf %s *.jar | wc -m
```

This will not count any newlines, just the filename characters (replace `wc -m` with `wc -c` for the number of bytes instead of characters).

Purposefully, I'm not [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Note that in shells like `bash`,  if there's no `.jar` file in the current directory, that will output `5` (the number of characters in `*.jar`). In `bash`, you can do `shopt -s nullglob` to get 0 in that case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the point of the `sed` command, you are replacing a slash with a space? Why?

Aside from that, it seems that you want to count the total number of characters in all the file names of the .jar files. IF so, try this:
`ls  /usr/hdp/2.6.4.0-91/tez_hive2/lib/*.jar  | sed s'/// /g' | wc -c`

Two other possibilities for your sed command:
 `sed "s|/| |g"` -- or -- `tr '/' ' '`
Since your *ls* command won't show directory names, I am not sure you need it.
This will also count the LF at the end of each file name. Is that OK?